# Column Name already belongs to datatable

Tags: vb.net, gridview, webforms

I try to copy from one gridview to another gridview 
i try this

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable()

    For Each cell As TableCell In GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells
        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text)
    Next

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        dt.Rows.Add()
        For i As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
            dt.Rows(row.RowIndex)(i) = row.Cells(i).Text

        Next
    Next

    GridView2.DataSource = dt
    GridView2.DataBind()
```

but this shows an error

```
A column named 'Amount' already belongs to this DataTable.
```

where as i SP i don't have duplicate columns

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see all cell.Text values?

Comment: yes all comes correctly but on amount this shows an error

Comment: have you checked if in the first loop there are two header-cells with the same text "Amount"? The exception is thrown in the first loop when you add a second column with the same name as another. How you build the GridView-header, is it static?

Comment: no there is 2 header text with text "Amount " .. i transfer data from one gridview to another

Comment: @TimSchmelter ???????

Comment: "no, there is 2 header text with text "Amount""? That means there are two headers with the same text? Or you wanted to say "No, there are not 2 headers with...."?

Comment: first one is true..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have commented that you really have two header-cells with the same text `"Amount"`. You cant add two columns with the same name to a `DataTable`, so you have to assign a different name or let it generate automatically, f.e. `Amount_2`, `Amount_3`,...:

This version that uses `Substring` and `LastIndexOf` handles also the case that the column-name could contain underscores:

```
For Each cell In tableCells
    Dim colName = cell
    While dt.Columns.Contains(colName)
        Dim lastUnderscoreIndex = colName.LastIndexOf("_"c)
        Dim colNameWithoutNum = If(lastUnderscoreIndex > -1, colName.Remove(lastUnderscoreIndex), colName)
        Dim numPart = If(lastUnderscoreIndex > -1, colName.Substring(lastUnderscoreIndex + 1), "")
        Dim num As Int32 = If(Int32.TryParse(numPart, num), num + 1, 2)
        colName = $"{colNameWithoutNum}_{num}"
    End While
    dt.Columns.Add(colName)
Next
```

Comment: that's nice code, things i've never seen/used. is this `$"{colNameWithoutNum}_{num}"` available in c#? i don't even know what to call it.

Comment: @wazz String Interpolation, and yes, it has been in C# longer than VB.

Comment: Yes, it's the same syntax in C# and is available with C#6 or Visual Basic 14. But you can also use string concatenation or `String.Format`. @AFriend: C# and VB.NET got it at the same, with VS 2015.

Comment: sry, i have distracted you. it's not my OP. ; )